# Calculating angular momentum from the Hydrogen wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, wavefunction, home-experiment

I am trying to calculate the magnitude of the angular momentum of an electron in a Hydrogen atom from its wavefunction given by

$$ \psi(r, \theta, \phi) = \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2 \pi}} (\frac{1}{a_0})^{\frac{2}{3}} \frac{r}{a_0} \exp({\frac{-r}{2a_0}}) \cos\theta, $$

where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius.

Frankly, I have no idea where to start with this problem.

Comment: What spherical harmonics do you identify?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the quantity "angular momentum" is just defined for eigenstates of the angular momentum. If the given state is not an eigenstate of the angular momentum, all you can do is calculate the expectance value of the angular momentum operator, but the quantity itself then is not clearly defined for this wave function.

This problem can now be solved in two ways: The first way is to calculate the expectance value of the angular momentum operator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator). This is defined as $\langle\psi|L|\psi\rangle$. You can just integrate this and will get the expectance value as a result.

The second way is in my opinion the more elegant way. You know, that the potential of the hydrogen atom is spherically symmetric and therefore it's eigenstates are also eigenstates of the angular momentum operator. Therefore you can use the general formula for the wave functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom) and calculate the overlap integral of the given wave function with each eigenfunction of the hydrogen atom $\langle\psi|\psi_{nlm}\rangle$. For each eigenfunction of the hydrogen atom the angular momentum is known. The expectance value of the total angular momentum will then be $$\langle L\rangle=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{l(l+1)
\hbar}\ \cdot|\ \langle\psi|\psi_{nlm}\rangle|^2$$ Although this sum looks very complicated, in most cases just a few of the scalar products will be unlike zero. In the case that your function is an eigenfunction, just one term will be unlike zero.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be "a" magnitude, unless the state is an eigenstate of $\hat L^2$, that is:

$$\hat L^2\psi = |L|^2\psi $$

So apply the operator:

$$ \hat L^2 = -\hbar^2\Big[
\frac 1 {\sin{\theta}}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
\big(\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\big)+
\frac 1{\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}
\Big]$$

and see what happens.

You should find:

$$ \hat L^2\psi=2\hbar^2\psi \equiv l(l+1)\hbar^2\psi$$

where $l$ is the orbital angular momentum quantum number.